# Adding a condition to my mysql query gives invalid use of group function error

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am trying to get a result set by combining 2 sql queries

1. I have to get the max(user_count) for a particular app by the following query

**select max(user_count) as TotalUsers, host_app_id as host_id from pg_datascience.hostapp_apps group by host_app_id order by TotalUsers desc;**

2. I have to get the TotalUsers and host_id from above query in this query as below

select distinct(app_id), max(user_count), round((max(user_count)/TotalUsers * 100 ),2) AS percentage from pg_datascience.hostapp_apps where host_app_id = host_id group by app_id order by percentage desc;

I tried to club together these queries into a same query in the below query:

```
select distinct(a.app_id), 
    max(a.user_count) as users, 
    round((max(a.user_count)/b.TotalUsers * 100 ),2) AS percentage, 
    b.TotalUsers 
from pg_datascience.hostapp_apps as a 
JOIN 
(
    select max(user_count) as TotalUsers, 
            host_app_id as host_id 
    from pg_datascience.hostapp_apps 
    group by host_app_id order by TotalUsers desc
) b 
on (host_app_id = b.host_id) 
group by a.app_id order by percentage desc;
```

Now my concern is I have to filter and remove the record if the **max(a.user_count) as users** is less than 10000

I tried to use where clause

```
select distinct(a.app_id), 
    max(a.user_count) as users, 
    round((max(a.user_count)/b.TotalUsers * 100 ),2) AS percentage, 
    b.TotalUsers 
from pg_datascience.hostapp_apps as a 
JOIN 
(
    select max(user_count) as TotalUsers, 
    host_app_id as host_id 
    from pg_datascience.hostapp_apps 
    group by host_app_id 
    order by TotalUsers desc
) b 
on (host_app_id = b.host_id) **where 10000<=(max(a.user_count)** group by a.app_id order by percentage desc;
```

But I am getting invalid use of group function error.

Then I tried writing a separate subquery for it

```
select distinct(a.app_id), 
        max(a.user_count) as users, 
        round((max(a.user_count)/b.TotalUsers * 100 ),2) AS percentage, 
        b.TotalUsers 
from pg_datascience.hostapp_apps as a 
JOIN 
(
    select max(user_count) as TotalUsers, 
            host_app_id as host_id 
    from pg_datascience.hostapp_apps 
    group by host_app_id 
    order by TotalUsers desc
) b 
on (host_app_id = b.host_id) 
where **10000<=(select max(a.user_count) from pg_datascience.hostapp_apps as a)** 
group by a.app_id 
order by percentage desc;
```

But I am not getting the desired result as the result is still having apps with usercount>10000.

Is there any other way to get the desired result

Comment: Your question does not seem to be minimalistic, and a bit overwhelming to process. Without the minimal base table structure and required output let's just refer you to `having` clause of SQL `group by` and the use of ID based join of subselects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think you just need a HAVING clause to check the value after the GROUP BY

```
SELECT a.app_id, 
    MAX(a.user_count) AS users, 
    ROUND((MAX(a.user_count)/b.TotalUsers * 100 ),2) AS percentage, 
    b.TotalUsers 
FROM pg_datascience.hostapp_apps AS a 
JOIN 
(
    SELECT host_app_id AS host_id,
            MAX(user_count) AS TotalUsers
    FROM pg_datascience.hostapp_apps 
    GROUP BY host_app_id 
) b 
on (host_app_id = b.host_id) 
GROUP BY a.app_id,
        b.TotalUsers
HAVING users >= 10000
ORDER BY percentage desc;
```